# data-frame remove duplicate indexed rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame (df)

```
             mark
snap_time        
140000     8250.0
140000     8250.0
141000     8252.0
141000     8252.0
142000     8249.0
```

I'm trying to remove any rows with the same snap_time index

I've tried:

```
df.drop_duplicates(subset=None, keep=False, inplace=False)
```

But it's not removing the duplicate rows.

The desired output from this example would be:

```
             mark
snap_time        
140000     8250.0
141000     8252.0
142000     8249.0
```

Answer (score 0):

try explicitly telling which columns to check for matching duplicates

```
df.drop_duplicates(subset=['snap_time', 'mark'], keep=False)
```